# MATLAB: add field to structure within a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, field, structure, cell

I have a nested for loop and would like to create named fields within the first loop and then save to that field within the next loop. Something like the below code where the first iteration would create structure.first and add 'works' to that field. Thanks!

```
structure = [];
namelist = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
p = 5;
for i = 1:p
    structure(end+1) = struct(namelist(i), {});
    for j = 1:10
        if condition = true
            structure(j).namelist(i) = 'works';
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In the `if condition = true` case, should that be `structure(j)...`?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sure this is full of flaws, I've just started using structures so was just hoping to get enough code in to make it clear what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems with your code. Here's a cleaned up version. Note that the best way to add a field to a structure from a string value is of the form: `<<struct_name>>.(<<field_name_str>>) = <<value>>`. Also, the `if` statement tests whether a condition holds or not, so no need to test if it is true. Finally, `namelist` should be stored as a cell array.

```
structure = [];
namelist = {'first', 'second', 'third'};
for i = 1:length(namelist)
    for j = 1:10
        if condition
            structure.(namelist{i})='works';
        end
    end
end
```